# LoadLibrary fails when called from process run as Standard User on Windows Server 2008 with Terminal Services

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, uac, loadlibrary, terminal-services

We have a .NET library that platform invokes native code, specifically we call LoadLibrary().  This code has been in place for a while, but a new user has noticed when running as a Terminal Services user of a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine that it fails to run (apparently when LoadLibrary is called).  This happens when run as a Standard User but not when run as an admin which is suspicious.  Also it works when run on a Windows Server 2003 machine.

Now we've tested running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine and not had any issues before.

I'm suspicious that UAC is at play here.  We had them use Process Monitor and I noticed the result INVALID PARAMETER when DeviceIOControl() is called with the control code IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME.  Which also makes me suspicious of a mapped drive, though running the same code on a mapped drive on my machine works just fine.

Anybody have suggestions about what to try short of standing up a similar machine but the chances of us being able to replicate this in house are looking slim.

Comment: Do they really mean "when run as a standard user" or do they mean "when run as an administrative user but without elevation" ?  If they really do mean a standard user, UAC isn't involved.  (Have you tried Server 2003 as a standard user?)  If you can add diagnostics to your application, it would be useful to double-check the path being passed to LoadLibrary() as well as the error code it returns.

Answer (score 0):

For others who find themselves in a similar situation, the user was able to resolve the issue by altering their Software Restriction Group Policy.